# Possible to set geofence around specific points saved in database by an application?

Tags: geofencing

I am working on an application which I can use to create custom geo-fence.

For that, I want to get the coordinate of the location (latitude, longitude) and save that in the backend database using the app.

Now for each point saved, I want to create a geo-fence around each of those points, say with 10-KM radius.

The entry and exit action for all of them will be same.

How to accomplish this ? Can be be done ?

Comment: Do you want to use a geospatial database, like postgres with postgis?

Comment: I'll have to go with database provided to me. Not sure what that will be. Is there any service like backendless which provides postgis/postgres ?

Comment: If you use openlayers, it have methods to obtain the geometry of the polygon( in text or byte form) after the draw in the map, so could you save it maybe in a text column in any database, and have the logic to draw the geofence in the frontend

Comment: What's this question got to do with the type of database being used? If you're storing longitude and latitude then all you need is a basic SQLite table with a couple of `double`s. Why complicate matters? Or am I missing something? I thought the question was about creating a Geofence (which is pretty straightforward). Why is everyone getting hung up on the database???

Comment: The problem is creating GeoFence in the server side.